# Variable resetting upon end of def

Tags: python

I started learning Python only a few days ago but I decided to test my skills by making a simple X O game, and below is the code I have written so far. 
hopefully, it doesn't require explanation. but basically what happens is after one of the functions ends and goes on to the other the numbers reset, so when player one inputs "1" and X is placed in position 1 and then player two inputs "2" and O is placed in position 2, the X that player one inputted goes back to being "1". 
How do I fix this?

```
grid=" %s | %s | %s \n --+---+--\n %s | %s | %s\n --+---+--\n %s | %s | %s"  
one = "1" 
two = "2" 
three = "3" 
four = "4"
five = "5" 
six = "6" 
seven = "7" 
eight = "8" 
nine = "9" 
error = "\n error" 
print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)

def pleone(m, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine): 
    if m == "1":
        one = "X"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        pltwo()   
    elif m == "2":
        two = "X"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        pltwo()   
    elif m == "3":
        three = "X"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        pltwo()   
    elif m == "4":
        four = "X"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        pltwo()  
    elif m == "5":
        five = "X"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        pltwo()   
    elif m == "6":
        six = "X"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        pltwo()   
    elif m == "7":
        seven = "X"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        pltwo()   
    elif m == "8":
        eight = "X"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        pltwo()   
    elif m == "9":
        nine = "X"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        pltwo()   
    else:
        print error

def pletwo(k, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine): 
    if k == "1":
        one = "O"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        plone()   
    elif k == "2":
        two = "O"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        plone()   
    elif k == "3":
        three = "O"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        plone()   
    elif k == "4":
        four = "O"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        plone()   
    elif k == "5":
        five = "O"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        plone()   
    elif k == "6":
        six = "O"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        plone()   
    elif k == "7":
        seven = "O"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        plone()   
    elif K == "8":
        eight = "O"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        plone()   
    elif k == "9":
        nine = "O"
        print grid % (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)
        plone()   
    else:
        print error

def plone():   
    m = raw_input("\n player one (X), what position? ")  
    pleone(m, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)

def pltwo():   
    k = raw_input("\n player two (O), what position? ")  
    pletwo(k, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine)

plone()
```

Answer (score 2):

I left your code as is, but you can beautify it.

The reason for the change back to '1' is that the 'one' outside the pleone and pletwo functions is not the same as the 'one' inside the functions.

The outside 'one' has global scope, while the 'one' inside the functions have local scope, meaning that they only are valid inside the function.

You need to declare the variable inside the functions as global to be able to change it.

The following example shows how to fix this:

```
g_var = '1'
l_var = '1'

print g_var, l_var # prints 1, 1, the values of the global variables


def my_func():
    global g_var # the keyword global tells that we want to change the global variable g_var

    g_var = '2'
    l_var = '2'

    print g_var, l_var # prints 2, 2, the first being the value of the global variable, the second being the local declared variable l_var.

my_func()

print g_var, l_var # prints 2, 1, again the values of both global declared variables
```

Comment: i tried adding global in front of the "one" var but it just displays this error:

Comment: global one = "X"
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you need to do it like this:

global one
one = "X"

(each on a new line)